# How to convert methods in react class components to functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react to build a radar chart. found this editable [source](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery/radar-chart/). But it is in react class components. I need to convert it to functional components.

Original Class component: [enter link description here](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery/radar-chart/)

I tried converting the class component to functional component but could not find a way to convert the following two methods in the class.

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.processData(characterData),
      maxima: this.getMaxima(characterData)
    };
  }

  getMaxima(data) {
    const groupedData = Object.keys(data[0]).reduce((memo, key) => {
      memo[key] = data.map((d) => d[key]);
      return memo;
    }, {});
    return Object.keys(groupedData).reduce((memo, key) => {
      memo[key] = Math.max(...groupedData[key]);
      return memo;
    }, {});
  }

  processData(data) {
    const maxByGroup = this.getMaxima(data);
    const makeDataArray = (d) => {
      return Object.keys(d).map((key) => {
        return { x: key, y: d[key] / maxByGroup[key] };
      });
    };
    return data.map((datum) => makeDataArray(datum));
  }
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```js
    const [data, setData] = useState(characterData);
const [maxima, setMaxima] = useState(characterData);

  setMaxima = (data: any[]) => {
    const groupedData = Object.keys(data[0]).reduce((memo, key) => {
      memo[key] = data.map(d => d[key]);
      return memo;
    }, {});
    return Object.keys(groupedData).reduce((memo, key) => {
      memo[key] = Math.max(...groupedData[key]);
      return memo;
    }, {});
  };

  setData = (data: any[]) => {
    const maxByGroup = setMaxima(data);
    const makeDataArray = (d: { [x: string]: number }) =>
      Object.keys(d).map(key => ({ x: key, y: d[key] / maxByGroup[key] }));
    return data.map(datum => makeDataArray(datum));
  };
```

Can somebody please help me to convert these two methods to functions. The problem here is these are the set methods of useState functions.

Comment: They're both quite pure functions already that take their input as arguments and give their output as return values. Not much to change except for `function` syntax. Please show us your attempts!

Comment: I updated the question. Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console ??

Comment: Why did you rename them?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the functions in `const` in functional components. Try like below,

```
  const [data, setData] = useState(characterData);
  const [maxima, setMaxima] = useState(characterData);

  const setMaxima1 = (data: any[]) => {
    const groupedData = Object.keys(data[0]).reduce((memo, key) => {
      memo[key] = data.map(d => d[key]);
      return memo;
    }, {});
    setMaxima(value)
    return Object.keys(groupedData).reduce((memo, key) => {
      memo[key] = Math.max(...groupedData[key]);
      return memo;
    }, {});

  };

  const setData1 = (data: any[]) => {
    const maxByGroup = setMaxima(data);
    const makeDataArray = (d: { [x: string]: number }) =>
      Object.keys(d).map(key => ({ x: key, y: d[key] / maxByGroup[key] }));
    setData(Value)
    return data.map(datum => makeDataArray(datum));
  };
```

Comment: That'll still throw a quite obvious error

Comment: but `setData` and `setMaxima` are already defined in useState. why do we redefined them as `const setData ..... etc? Those two methods are in the original class component. I'm facing this issue. (if you refer to the original file in 'Victory Native': https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery/radar-chart/

Comment: Oh I dint check it. Then it is better to rename the function and set the value inside the function. i.e.., setMaxima(Value). That cannot be used as a  function.

Comment: I have edited it. Try as above now..,

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing to do is to just write them as regular functions and remove all the `this` in the code because they are already fairly pure functions:

```
  function MyComponent (props) {
    [data, setData] = useState(processData(characterData));
    [maxima, setMaxima] = useState(getMaxima(characterData));

    function getMaxima (data) {
      const groupedData = Object.keys(data[0]).reduce((memo, key) => {
        memo[key] = data.map((d) => d[key]);
        return memo;
      }, {});
      return Object.keys(groupedData).reduce((memo, key) => {
        memo[key] = Math.max(...groupedData[key]);
        return memo;
      }, {});
    }

    function processData (data) {
      const maxByGroup = getMaxima(data);
      const makeDataArray = (d) => {
        return Object.keys(d).map((key) => {
          return { x: key, y: d[key] / maxByGroup[key] };
        });
      };
      return data.map((datum) => makeDataArray(datum));
    }
  }
```